# Addressing pins of Register in microcontrollers

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, keil, addressing

I'm working on Keil software and using LM3S316 microcontroller. Usually we address registers in microcontrollers in form of:

```
#define GPIO_PORTC_DATA_R       (*((volatile uint32_t *)0x400063FC))
```

My question is how can I access to single pin of register for example, if I have this method:

```
char process_key(int a)
{  PC_0 = a ;}
```

How can I get PC_0 and how to define it?

Thank you

Comment: masking and shifting.  depending on the microcontroller some have ways to set or clear bits in a register without a read-modify-write.

Comment: the cortex-m has a bit banding feature that you read about as well.

Comment: @old_timer I looked at the [data sheet](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/luminary/lm3s316.pdf), there do not appear to be bit set/bit reset registers in the GPIO map on LM3S316.

Comment: yep, I did too,  it appears for that part either read-modify-write with the data register or use bit banding if available.  We are not hear to read the manuals for the OP, not the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given say:

```
#define PIN0 (1u<<0)
#define PIN1 (1u<<1)
#define PIN2 (1u<<2)
// etc...
```

Then:

```
char process_key(int a)
{  
    if( a != 0 )
    {
        // Set bit
        GPIO_PORTC_DATA_R |= PIN0 ;
    }
    else
    {
        // Clear bit
        GPIO_PORTC_DATA_R &= ~PIN0 ;
    }
}
```

A generalisation of this idiomatic technique is presented at [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit/47990#47990)

However the read-modify-write implied by `|=` / `&=` can be problematic if the register might be accessed in different thread/interrupt contexts, as well as adding a possibly undesirable overhead.  Cortex-M3/4 parts have a feature known as bit-banding that allows individual bits to be addressed directly and atomically.  Given:

```
volatile uint32_t* getBitBandAddress( volatile const void* address, int bit )
{
    __IO uint32_t* bit_address = 0;
    uint32_t addr = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(address);

    // This bit maniplation makes the function valid for RAM
    // and Peripheral bitband regions
    uint32_t word_band_base = addr & 0xf0000000u;
    uint32_t bit_band_base = word_band_base | 0x02000000u;
    uint32_t offset = addr - word_band_base;

    // Calculate bit band address
    bit_address = reinterpret_cast<__IO uint32_t*>(bit_band_base + (offset * 32u) + (static_cast<uint32_t>(bit) * 4u));

    return bit_address ;
}
```

Then you can have:

```
char process_key(int a)
{  
    static volatile uint32_t* PC0_BB_ADDR = getBitBandAddress( &GPIO_PORTC_DATA_R, 0 ) ;

    *PC0_BB_ADDR = a ;
}
```

You could of course determine and hard-code the bit-band address; for example:

```
#define PC0 (*((volatile uint32_t *)0x420C7F88u))
```

Then:

```
char process_key(int a)
{  
    PC0 = a ;
}
```

Details of the bit-band address calculation can be found [ARM Cortex-M Technical Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.100165_0201_02_en/ric1417175913696.html), and there is an on-line calculator [here](http://%20http://www.efton.sk/STM32/bitbandcalc.html).

Comment: Just a nit-pick: make sure to always write `1u<<n`. Because `1<<31` invokes undefined behavior on ARM since `1` is a signed integer type. Similarly, use `u` suffix on all hex constants too, or they might end up as different types. `0xf0000000` is for example type unsigned int, while `0x02000000` is type signed int. If unlucky, you may end up with some subtle bugs because of wrong signedness.

Comment: @Lundin I would not be at all offended had you edited it - though not your job to fix my errors of course.  Will fix.  The bit band address code I copy and pasted from an old answer (of mine) elsewhere.  I am pretty sure the version I currently use has better type agreement since it will have since been through static analysis - but I did not have access to that version at the time.  Was missing the `0x` prefix on the PC0 def too - also fixed.